# undefined Reference to std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const: 0509-036 Cannot load program on AIX7.1 using GCC4.8.5

Tags: c++, linker, runtime, aix, gcc4.8

I am able to Build my project on Linux and AIX successfully but I'm facing following error while trying to run it.

```
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program ./xmlformcmd because of the following errors:
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol _ZNKSt9type_infoeqERKS_ was referenced
      from module 
libpdfl.so(), but a runtime definition of the symbol was not found
```

upon demangling above symbol I get

```
std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const
```

I have built the project using gcc4.8.5 on AIX7.1. I tried it on AIX 6.1 too with the GCC4.8.5 and I was facing the same issue.

It runs fine on Linux machine using gcc4.8.5 but failing on AIX.

tried with gcc4.4.4 it throws the same error with gcc 4.4.4.

edit 1: tried using `-Wl,--no-undefined` falg just to make sure it fails in case of mssing symbol definition but build succeed even after adding this flag and runtime fails throwing same error

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful it is, but the demangled function is `std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const`. Missing or bad dynamic library, possibly?

Comment: This symbol should come from `libstdc.a` or `libstdc.so`. You might want to read this: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0004

Comment: Thanks for the help!! setting the LIBPATH variable to `/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/lib` and `/user/unicore/rs6000aix/compiler/gcc4.8.5/aix6.1/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.8.5` solved the problem. followed the step mentioned in the very 1st question